# Getting the path of an image stored locally from a JSON file - React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I've been looking for a way to get paths of images stored locally in my project from a **JSON file**.
I already saw answers suggesting dropping the **JSON file** and using an array in a **.JS file** instead, just like this :

```
const DATA = [
   {
    "ID": 0,
    "Image": require('../assets/image0.png')
   },
   {
    "ID": 1,  
    "Image": require('../assets/image1.png')
   }
]
```

Thing is I can solely use a **JSON file** to get my data from, which results from converting an **Excel** to **JSON file**, and nothing else. So let's say I have a **data.json** file as follows :

```
{  
  "data": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "Image": "require('../assets/image0.png')"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,  
            "Image": "require('../assets/image1.png')"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, it is not possible to use the paths stored in the "Image" attributs as a source in  `<Image source = {}/>` to display an image. Does somebody know a way to conserve the **JSON** file and somehow get and use the paths from it ?

EDIT :

My structure  :

```
- assets
       - favicon.png // Image I want to display
       - icon.png // Image I want to display
- screens
       - File1.js // Where I want to display images
       - images.json // From where to get paths
```

File1.js

```
 // Other imports
 import assets from "./images.json;
 require("../assets/favicon.png");
 require("../assets/icon.png");

const File1 = () => {
    return (
       <View>
        {assets.data.map((i) => (
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: require(i.Image.replace("require('", "").replace("')", ""))
              }}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={styles.logo}
            />
          ))}
            {/*<Image source={require('../assets/favicon.png')}></Image> Its working but not above*/}
      </View>
    )
};

export default File1;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   logo: {
        height: 80
    },
});
```

images.json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "Image": "require('../assets/favicon.png')"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Image": "require('../assets/icon.png')"
        }
    ]
}
```

But getting :

```
TransformError src\screens\File1.js: src\screens\File1.js:Invalid call at line 323: require(i.Image.replace("require('", "").replace("')", ""))
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:320:31 in showCompileError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:227:26 in client.on$argument_1
- node_modules\eventemitter3\index.js:181:21 in emit
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\bundle-modules\HMRClient.js:142:10 in _ws.onmessage
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\WebSocket\WebSocket.js:231:8 in _eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store in an array only the path, for example:

```
const images = {data : [
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "Image": "require('../assets/image0.png')"
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,  
        "Image": "require('../assets/image1.png')"
    }
]}
```

and in your render component:

```
return (<>{
images.data.map(i => <Image source={require(i.Image.replace("require('", "").replace("')", ""))}/>)
}</>)
```

Comment: Not only it doesn't work, but itll need me to create an array of objects and MANUALLY specify the paths which is something I don't want to. I want to preserve my JSON and get the paths from it.

Comment: Your json is not a correctly formatted json

Comment: Fixed typo. Care to look at the question now ?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can remove the require staff from the string to get the path and use require in the image

Comment: Still getting invalid call in require.

Comment: As the require is static, it'll be compiled at start, so you need to import all the image before using it with the json. If this is feasable for you, I prepared a codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-jackson-0j2zg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I mean, I took some parts of your code and used it in my current project as you can see in my edited original post. However, I still got an error.. Is this supposed to work on React Native for a Mobile App ? Because your sample specifies "React Native for Web" so I don't know.